# Before action after delete model Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How to write action that is called after destroy in model:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {

        Announcement::destroy($id);
        return redirect("announcements/my")->with('success', "Success!");
    }
```

Comment: What kind of action are we talking about?

Comment: Delete action...

Comment: @Darama What action do you want to take after a delete?

Comment: Can you share sample, because tutorial is not clear

Comment: @Darama A sample of **what**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Eloquent Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events) to do that.